# smarter character replacement using ruby gsub and regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, replace, gsub

I'm trying to create permalink like behavior for some article titles and i don't want to add a new db field for permalink. So i decided to write a helper that will convert my article title from:

"*O "focoasă" a pornit cruciada, împotriva bărbaţilor zgârciţi*" to 
 "*o-focoasa-a-pornit-cruciada-impotriva-barbatilor-zgarciti*".

While i figured out how to replace spaces with hyphens and remove other special characters (other than -) using:

```
title.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
```

I am wondering if there is any other way to replace a character with a specific other character from only one .gsub method call, so I won't have to chain title.gsub("ă", "a") methods for all the UTF-8 special characters of my localization.

I was thinking of building a hash with all the special characters and their counterparts but I haven't figured out yet how to use variables with regexps.

What I was looking for is something like:

```
title.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(*replace character goes here*).gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this in my application by using the [Unidecoder](https://rubygems.org/gems/unidecoder) gem:

```
require 'unidecode'

def uninternationalize(str)
  Unidecoder.decode(str).gsub("[?]", "").gsub(/`/, "'").strip
end
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! after installing the gem i couldn't get it to work with require 'unicode' so i added 
config.gem 'unidecode', :version => '~> 1.0.0', :source => 'http://rubyforge.org' to my enviroment file.

Then in the helper I just created the method and that was it!

def permalink(title)
    Unidecoder.decode(title).gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
  end

Comment: If you were trying to require 'unicode', that would be your problem, the gem is 'unidecode' ;)

Comment: Damn! you're right :) That's what i get for working this late. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to only transliterate from one character to another, you can use the `String#tr` method which does exactly the same thing as the Unix `tr` command: replace every character in the first list with the character in the same position in the second list:

```
'Ünicöde'.tr('ÄäÖöÜüß', 'AaOoUus') # => "Unicode"
```

However, I agree with @Daniel Vandersluis: it would probably be a good idea to use some more specialized library. Stuff like this can get really tedious, really fast. Also, a lot of those characters actually have standardized transliterations (ä → ae, ö → oe, ..., ß → ss), and users may be expecting to have the transliterations be correct (I certainly don't like being called Jorg – if you really must, you may call me Joerg but I very much prefer Jörg) and if you have a library that provides you with those transliterations, why not use them? Note that there are a lot of transliterations which are not single characters and thus can't be used with `String#tr` anyway.