# Soft signs in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I want to create multiple categories via console and I want to be able add soft signs. At this moment I can't do that.

It's very important to project that I can save category names with soft signs.

Can somebody tip me where to search? I searched such tag -  soft signs rails.
There wasn't any usefull resource.

Thanks

EDIT

Soft signs in my native language is like this.

Ā,Š,Ē,Ž with that symbol called soft sign abowe the character.

---

At this moment when I try to save new category record it shows me this kind off error 
`thodError: undefined method`cache_ancestry!' for #

But I am sure that I didn't change anything in models or controllers :(

Comment: Have you thought of character replacement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678160/smarter-character-replacement-using-ruby-gsub-and-regexp

Comment: Do you mean soft sign -- the Cyrillic character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign)? Besides that, we need some code to help you. Categories of what? What are your models? Have you already tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Ruby is this? What you're seeing there are either US-ASCII strings with UTF-8 data in them (Ruby 1.9) or byte arrays (Ruby 1.8).

If you're using Ruby 1.8, you may need to use Iconv to convert your encoding from US-ASCII to UTF-8. If you're using Ruby 1.9, then make sure you're creating UTF-8 strings and it should work just fine.

Note that those escape sequences are correct - that is the literal byte array of those characters, assuming the proper encoding is applied, so you may not need to actually change anything. If the bytes are right, everything's fine - you're just seeing ruby interpret the string as ASCII rather than UTF-8 or whatnot.

In Ruby 1.8, when you `#inspect` a string, you get the escaped version, but `puts`ing it will show you the actual string:

```
1.8.7 :021 > s = "Komunālās mašīnas"
 => "Komun\304\201l\304\201s ma\305\241\304\253nas"
1.8.7 :022 > puts s
Komunālās mašīnas
```

In 1.9, you get the correct display all around, so long as your encoding is right:

```
1.9.3p327 :001 > s = "Komunālās mašīnas"
 => "Komunālās mašīnas"
1.9.3p327 :004 > s.force_encoding "US-ASCII"
 => "Komun\xC4\x81l\xC4\x81s ma\xC5\xA1\xC4\xABnas"
1.9.3p327 :005 > puts s
Komunālās mašīnas
```

Comment: `irb(main):002:0> t.name = "Atkritumu pārstrādes tehnika"
=> "Atkritumu p\x83rstr\x83des tehnika"
irb(main):003:0> t.save
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mrollback transaction←[0m
NameError: undefined local variable or method `cache_ancestry' for #<Category:0x2ebc960>`

Comment: it happens all the time I want to save record. No matter with soft signs or without them.

Comment: I can paste the escape string and it parses correctly, but I can not write `"Komunālās mašīnas"` else it omits the characters it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out Edgars:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
t = 'ŠšÐŽžÀÁÂÃÄAÆAÇÈÉÊËÌÎÑNÒOÓOÔOÕOÖOØOUÚUUÜUÝYÞBßSàaáaâäaaæaçcèéêëìîðñòóôõöùûýýþÿƒ'
fallback = { 
  'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
  'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
  'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
  'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
  'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
  'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
  'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'
  }

p t.encode('us-ascii', :fallback => fallback)
```

See [Ruby 1.9.x replace sets of characters with specific cleaned up characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810489/ruby-1-9-x-replace-sets-of-characters-with-specific-cleaned-up-characters-in-a-s)

EDIT:

To get all the characters for your language you will need to add them as desired to the fallback hash. When I run "Komunālās mašīnas" as the variable 't' I get this:

```
t = "Komunālās mašīnas"
t.encode('us-ascii', :fallback => fallback)
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+0101 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
```

You can tell from this where the problem lies by googling U+0101 which shows

http://www.charbase.com/0101-unicode-latin-small-letter-a-with-macron

So now you know which letter is not working and you can add it to the fallback hash like so:

```
fallback = { OTHER DEFINITIONS , 'ā'=>'a'}
```

Here's a place to start:

http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp775.html

Comment: Great, but this won't work because in Latvian alphabet there is characters like A and Ā and they have completely different meaning. For example in console I am writting A with meaning to be Ā. Ok. then your suggestion works, but if I want to write A with meaning A. How then it goes ? Tnx